# Crash when presenting in popover on ios6

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller

Having a confusing issue:

I have a view controller (`settingsViewVontroller)`, which presents another VC (`colorPickerController`) which is embedded in a navigation controller. On iPhone, settingsViewController is presented modally. On iPad, it's presented in a popover.  In both cases, the navigation controller is presented modally to cover settingsViewController -- full screen on  the iPhone, and within the enclosing popover on iPad.

Works fine in both cases on ios7, but on ios6 for iPad, it crashes trying to modally present the navigation controller containing the color picker.  I get an autolayout error saying the constraints can't be reconciled, and it appears to be an issue with the navigation bar...

Why would this be working on ios7 but not 6?

**Update:** some code:

From within the popover, presenting the color picker modally:

```
ColorPickerViewController *cpcontroller = [[ColorPickerViewController alloc] init];
    cpcontroller.delegate = self;
    cpcontroller.selectedColor = self.frameColorButton.backgroundColor;
    cpcontroller.title = @"Frame Color";
    UINavigationController* navVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:cpcontroller];
    navVC.delegate = self;

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        navVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
        //navVC.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320, 568);
        //controller.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320,568);
        //controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    }

    [self presentViewController:navVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The three commented-out lines: I've tested with each of them "on" or "off", no change.

Here's the text of the error:

```
2014-08-09 09:30:28.248 appname[16865:907] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xa73dc70 H:[UINavigationBar:0xa992cb0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0xa6db840 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xa73dc30 H:|-(0)-[UINavigationBar:0xa992cb0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0xa6db840 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xa73fbd0 H:[UINavigationBar:0xa992cb0(320)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xa6dcfe0 h=--& v=--& UILayoutContainerView:0xa711050.width == UIView:0xa711370.width + 320>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xa6f5d40 h=-&- v=-&- UIView:0xa6db840.width == UILayoutContainerView:0xa711050.width>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xa6f86d0 h=--& v=--& H:[UIView:0xa711370(320)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0xa73fbd0 H:[UINavigationBar:0xa992cb0(320)]>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
```

Comment: Please add the symbolicated crash report and also the relevant code

Comment: @Kerni Updated, see above.

Comment: Are you using storyboard or .xib files ? In iOS 7, the behavior is really different. Check this tutorial to adapt the constraints in iOS 6 and iOS 7 for the navigation bar / status bar: http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/12/reconciling-ios-6-ios-7-using-interface-builder/

Comment: Both the SettingsViewController and ColorPickeViewrController load their views from .xib's.  Will look at that tutorial... Thanks!